# BASH Downloading File

Tags: bash, files, downloads

Now all I have problems with is the yes no statements. They aren't allowing input but look setup like the rest of them...

```
mc_addplugin() {
    if pgrep -u $USERNAME -f $SERVICE > /dev/null
    then
        echo "$SERVICE is running!"
        echo "Please stop the service before adding a plugin."
    else
        echo "Paste the URL to the .JAR Plugin..."
        read JARURL
        JARNAME=$(basename "$JARURL")
        echo "$JARNAME"
        if [ -d "$TEMPPLUGINS" ]
        then
            as_user "cd $TEMPLUGINS && wget -A.jar -O ./$JARNAME $JARURL"
        else
            as_user "cd $PLUGINSPATH && mkdir $TEMPPLUGINS && cd $TEMPPLUGINS && wget -A.jar -O ./$JARNAME $JARURL"
        fi
        if [ -f "./$JARNAME" ]
        then
            as_user "cd $PLUGINSPATH"
            if [ -f "./$JARNAME" ]
            then
                if `diff $PLUGINSPATH/$JARNAME $TEMPPLUGINS/$JARNAME >/dev/null`
                then 
                    echo "You are already running the latest version of $JARNAME."
                    NOW=`date "+%Y-%m-%d_%Hh%M"`
                    echo "Are you sure you want to overwrite this plugin? [Y/n]"
                    echo "Note: Your old plugin will be moved to the "$TEMPPLUGINS" folder with todays date."
                    select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
                        case $yn in
                            Yes ) as_user "mv $PLUGINSPATH/$JARNAME $TEMPPLUGINS/${JARNAME}_${NOW} && mv $TEMPPLUGINS/$JARNAME $PLUGINSPATH/$JARNAME && rm -rf $TEMPPLUGINS";
                                    echo "Plugin has been install successfully!"; break;;
                            No ) echo "The plugin has not been installed! Removing temporary plugin and exiting..."
                                as_user "rm $TEMPPLUGINS/$JARNAME"; exit;;
                        esac
                    done
                    echo "Would you like to start the $SERVICE now? [Y/n]"
                    select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
                        case $yn in
                            Yes ) mc_start; break;;
                            No ) "$SERVICE not running! To start the service run: /etc/init.d/craftbukkit start"; exit;;
                            esac
                    done
                else
                    NOW=`date "+%Y-%m-%d_%Hh%M"`
                    echo "Are you sure you want to overwrite this plugin? [Y/n]"
                    echo "Note: Your old plugin will be moved to the "$TEMPPLUGINS" folder with todays date."
                    select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
                        case $yn in
                            Yes ) as_user "mv $PLUGINSPATH/$JARNAME $TEMPPLUGINS/${JARNAME}_${NOW} && mv $TEMPPLUGINS/$JARNAME $PLUGINSPATH/$JARNAME && rm -rf $TEMPPLUGINS";
                                    echo "Plugin has been install successfully!"; break;;
                            No ) echo "The plugin has not been installed! Removing temporary plugin and exiting..."
                                as_user "rm $TEMPPLUGINS/$JARNAME"; exit;;
                        esac
                    done
                    echo "Would you like to start the $SERVICE now? [Y/n]"
                    select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
                        case $yn in
                            Yes ) mc_start; break;;
                            No ) "$SERVICE not running! To start the service run: /etc/init.d/craftbukkit start"; exit;;
                            esac
                    done
                fi
            else
                echo "Are you sure you want to add this new plugin? [Y/n]"
                select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
                    case $yn in
                        Yes ) as_user "mv $PLUGINSPATH/$JARNAME $TEMPPLUGINS/${JARNAME}_${NOW} && mv $TEMPPLUGINS/$JARNAME $PLUGINSPATH/$JARNAME"; break;;
                        No ) echo "The plugin has not been installed! Removing temporary plugin and exiting..."
                            as_user "rm $TEMPPLUGINS/$JARNAME"; exit;;
                    esac
                done
                echo "Would you like to start the $SERVICE now? [Y/n]?"
                select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
                    case $yn in
                        Yes ) mc_start; break;;
                        No ) "$SERVICE not running! To start the service run: /etc/init.d/craftbukkit start"; exit;;
                    esac
                done
            fi
        else
            echo "Failed to download the plugin from the URL you specified!"
            exit;
        fi
    fi
}
```

When ran you get something like:

```
You are already running the latest version of Vault.jar.
Are you sure you want to overwrite this plugin? [Y/n]
Note: Your old plugin will be moved to the /home/pyrexiacraft/server/plugins/temp_plugins folder with todays date.
1) Yes
2) No
#? y
```

Comment: At the beginning of your script, you are cd'ing into the plugins path already. Why still use full paths then?

Comment: Not sure, that part directly is copied from someone script.

It's confusing becasue also while the jar is saved to $TEMPPLUGINS it's also saved in a folder within $PLUGINSPATH called 'dev.bukkit.org' is there a way to stop that?

And don't you need to use full paths to check a file exists anyway accurately?

Comment: Probably the pasted URL can't be *basenamed*. Maybe add another input to read directly into *JARNAME*.

Comment: How do you go about doing that? And the basename works just fine when outputted.

Comment: I've updated the post. It now all works besides the yes no statements. THey aren't allowing input. I get "#? y
#?

Comment: It is probably case sensitive - enter *Yes* instead of *y*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select` expects you to input the corresponding number; 1 for Yes or 2 for No in this case.

Still, the actual string the user typed in gets stored in the variable named `REPLY`, so you can parse that in addition to the numbers.

I'd just write a function for yes/no questions though; a yes/no query is not really what `select` is designed for. Something like

```
confirm() {
    local answer
    read -p "$1" -n1 answer
    while [[ $answer && $answer != [YyNn] ]]; do
        printf '\nPlease answer y or n\n' >&2
        read -p "$1" -n1 answer
    done
    printf '\n'
    [[ -z $answer || $answer = [Yy] ]]
}

#...

if confirm "Are you sure? [Y/n] "; then
    printf 'Ok\n'
else
    printf 'Fine, I will find something else to do\n'
fi
```

Y, y or ENTER will make the function return true, N or n will make the function return false. You could extend it to take the default value as a second argument.

Comment: That is a nifty function. Thank you for your time. That is much better then what I've found online.

Comment: @WASasquatch, yes, finding help for bash online is hard, because the overwhelming majority of bash guides, tutorials, examples, blogs etc are not very good, and often teaches/contains bugs, so google is not a good resource for bash. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ has a lot of answers you might find useful. Those are questions we get frequently on irc (#bash on freenode).